# What is the equivalent of JavaScript's `===` in Python, if it's not `is`?

Tags: python, python-3.x

In JavaScript, if I want to know if `foo == false` and `foo != 0` (or some other "falsy" value), I use `foo === false`, and that gives me a nice simple, exact comparison. It's even computationally faster because it doesn't try to test multiple types of equivalence. In Python the only equivalent I found to `===` and `!==` was `is` and `is not`. Now, after getting the `SyntaxWarning: "is" with a literal. Did you mean "=="?` error, and reading questions, answers, and articles about why `is` shouldn't be used in this, I'm left scratching my head.

For example:

```
def foo(bar=False):
    if bar != False:
        print(bar)
    else:
        print('default!')
```

Of course I ran into a case where `bar` was set to `0` and printed `default!`. I had been dealing with it like so:

```
def foo(bar=False):
    if bar is not False:
        print(bar)
    else:
        print('default!')
```

So if I'm not supposed to do that, what's the correct approach? Do I need to type out `bar != False and bar != 0` every time?

Comment: If you want to check if `bar` is the singleton boolean constant False, then `is` is the thing to use. But in general you should not need to do that, which is why your code might not be advisable.

Comment: Python is strongly typed, so it doesn't *need* the equivalent of `===`. `0` and `False` are a bad example, because `bool` is a subtype of `int`, so `0` and `False`, although distinct values, are equal.

Comment: Post the actual code that gave you that `SyntaxWarning` -- that's only supposed to be for comparison with literal numbers and strings. Testing `is False` is fine and should not produce it.

Comment: The correct approach is to avoid writing code that needs to distinguish between `0` and `False` in the first case.

Comment: @chepner is that normal in programming languages, to make no distinction between integers/floats and Booleans? Most of my experience is in JavaScript (where `0` and `false` are not equivalent) so it seems very odd to me. Is it a Python quirk, or something to expect in most languages?

Comment: @J.Todd It's not so much about the difference between the value (though IMO, `bool` doesn't need to be a subclass of `int`; it feels like an odd leftover from C), but in writing a function in which you have the option of passing an `int` or a `bool`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is :

```
def foo(bar=None):
    if bar is not None:
        print(bar)
    else:
        print('default!')
```

Only the 'None' object is identical to 'None' so any value of `bar` except `None` will print 'default'

Comment: Nothing else is _identical_ to None, it's a singleton.

Comment: if the `bar` argument I pass is an integer, won't the error still trigger through your code? I *think* you meant `bar != None` on line 2. Basically I want a simple way to check if a value is provided to the argument, or it's been left at default, that works in all cases. Including integers, which I think using `is` and `is not` to compare with integers or strings is what triggers the warning.

Comment: [docs:](https://docs.python.org/3/library/constants.html#None) "*None is the sole instance of the NoneType type.*"

Comment: Nothing else will be equal to `None`, but the recommended practice is to use `is` and `is not` with `None` to emphasize its status as a singleton.

Comment: Tldr, what I I'm trying to do, in case I wasn't clear: If an arg was provided, do this, else do that. The arg could be any type. If I understand right, if that arg is a number, this code using `is not` would complain about the comparison to an integer (or string), based on what I understand about everyone's explanations.

Comment: It's a (static) type error to pass `0` to a function that expects a Boolean value. Since Python is dynamically typed, you need 3rd-party tools like `mypy` to help you enforce such static typing (instead of relying on cumbersome runtime checks).

Comment: @J.Todd instead of print('default') do whatever you want to do if no arg is provided

Comment: @J.Todd try running the code and passing it different values, see how it behaves, `is not` will never give you a type error.

Comment: @jonrsharpe no value is identical to OR equivalent to 'None'  `None != False`  AND `None !=True`  but you're right, identical is more relevant to 'is not' .  so I updated it!

Comment: @JeffUK ahh so `is` and `is not` are not just inverses of the same check as I had misunderstood to be the case. Yes I just did test it and no error. ty

Comment: @chepner Using `is None` is not just done for emphasis.  It is possible for other objects to be == to None, if their `__eq__` method says so. And possible for `==` to do something else complicated, as a numpy sequence would.